# How to join two CSV files in python on a common column

Tags: python, csv

I have file1.csv containing following fields :

```
Name,EmailId,City
Roger,roger@gmail.com,pune
```

Second file file2.csv contains following fields:

```
City,State
Pune,Maharashtra
Mumbai,Maharashtra
```

So I want a output file containing :

```
Roger,roger@gmail.com,Pune,Maharashtra
```

How should I do it?
I have written the code below.

```
def getStateof():
    reader1 = csv.reader(open(r'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\compare\allUsers1.csv', 'r'), delimiter=',')
    reader2 = csv.reader(open(r'C:\Users\admin\Desktop\compare\mahrashtra.csv', 'r'), delimiter=',')
    for row1 in reader1: 
        for row2 in reader2:
            if(row1[5]==row2[1]):
                print(row1)
getStateof()
```

Comment: Presumably you also want column headers in the joined output: Name,EmailId,City,State.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Merge one dataframe onto another.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv')

df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='City')
```