# Applying python dictionary to column of a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, translate

I have a CSV file that includes one column data that is not user friendly. I need to translate that data into something that makes sense. Simple find/replace seems bulky since there are dozens if not hundreds of different possible combinations I want to translate.

For instance:  BLK = Black or MNT TP = Mountain Top

There are dozens if not hundreds of translations possible - I have lots of them already in a CSV table. The problem is how to use that dictionary to change the values in another CSV table. It is also important to note that this will (eventually) need to run on its own every few minutes - not just a one time translation.

Comment: Can you provide some sample input and sample output so we have an idea of what formats the CSVs are in?

Comment: What exactly is your programming question?

Comment: I need to take a CSV file that has one column of information that is essentially abbreviated and turn it into full words. For instance if I need "NB" to turn into "North Bound", or another example would be "BLND" to turn into "Blind". The file constantly updates so I need a script that can do this constantly - not just one time.

Comment: Your case looks like a classic (relational) join.  The following article may be relevant.  https://www.codespeedy.com/how-to-merge-two-csv-files-by-specific-column-in-python/#:~:text=We%20can%20merge%20on%20multiple%20columns%20by%20passing,of%20file2%20by%20using%20left_on%20and%20right_on%20argument.=

Comment: also the following. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48501791/how-to-join-two-csv-files-in-python-on-a-common-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be nice if you could describe in more detail what's the data you're working on. I'll do my best guess though.

Let's say you have a CSV file, you use `pandas` to read it into a data frame named `df`, and the "not user friendly" column named `col`.
To replace all the value in column `col`, first, you need a dictionary containing all the keys (original texts) and values (new texts):

```
my_dict = {"BLK": "Black", "MNT TP": Mountain Top,...}
```

Then, map the dictionary to the column:

```
df["col"] = df["col"].map(lambda x: my_dict.get(x, x))
```

If a key appears in the dictionary, it will be replaced by the new corresponding value in the dictionary, otherwise, it keeps the original value.

Comment: Okay this works! My only remaining issue is that it is saving as the original version (except a line number is added).  'df.to_csv('c:/PDW/converted.csv', header=False, mode = 'a')'

Comment: Actually this works! I just had a problem with the file not writing! Thank you.

Comment: Glad it could help! In your code, `mode='a'` means you will append the new output to the existing file. You can check at the end of the file, to see if it wrote something new in there. Also, you should mark my answer above (by clicking on the tick sign) so people can know it's solved.